# python regex usage: how to start with , least match , get content in middle

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a string like this:

> {"index":11,"trackId":1394194,"isPaid":false,"tag":0,"title":"诗经_009周南_汉广","playCount":323093,"showLikeBtn":true,"isLike":false,"showShareBtn":true,"showCommentBtn":true,"showForwardBtn":true,"createDateFormat":"7年前","url":"/renwen/221727/1394194","duration":61,"isVideo":false,"videoCover":null,"isVipFirst":false,"breakSecond":0,"length":61}

Here is the info I want

> 诗经_009周南_汉广

My solution is

```
result = re.findall(r'\"title\":(.*?)\"(.*?)\"', str)
```

and result is

> [ ('', '诗经_009周南_汉广')]

It start with `title`, `tag` is even better

do it greedy and least match to `广"` , then get content in middle

How to do it better?

Comment: Use `import json` and then `json.loads(s)["title"]` - https://ideone.com/UhJYvh

Comment: my situation is that , it is not simply json, it is json from webpage. I get this by `youtube-dl`, `webpage = self._download_webpage(url, audio_id,
                                         note='Download sound page for %s' % audio_id,
                                         errnote='Unable to get sound page')`

Comment: It is the same. You should "isolate", get the JSON using BeautifulSoup or other DOM parsing tool/library and then use JSON.

Comment: I strongly agree with @WiktorStribiżew. Don't re-implement what already exists, you will only make it worse (unless you really know what you are doing).

Comment: I agree also, https://ideone.com/ is nice